# Banshee doesn't support bubble notifications? (libnotify)

Tags: 11.04, unity, rhythmbox, banshee, notify-osd

I just installed Natty 64 bit. I love those Notify-OSD notifications in Rhythmbox but in Banshee they are not here. I guess that this is because of we can't minimize apps to tray (only to launcher).

So I installed Rhythmbox again... Notify OSD notifications works fine here but in this case I can't see Rhythmbox icon in the launcher. Any idea?

Comment: It should work. Check your Banshee extensions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be working. Check your Banshee extensions.

Open Banshee. Go to Edit > Preferences > In the General Tab select Show Banshee in Sound Menu under Miscellaneous.

Also under the Extensions tab check if you have Sound Menu Integration checked. If not check the box. The MPRIS D-BUs Interface extension should be checked automatically.

Then try to play. Should work.

Comment: what version of banshee do you have? those options are not in mine. Also, having "sound menu integration" enabled can cause some bugs with the actual sound menu integration - which seems to work just perfectly if the extension is disabled.

Comment: I use version 2.0.0. And Sound Menu Integration works perfectly well for me. Even if you disable it your Bubble Notifications should be working. Check if you have MPRIS D-Bus Interface extension checked.

Comment: I am not the op - i just added a comment. I probably have different menus cause i use a newer version of banshee.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check "Sound Menu Integration" under the extensions tab.

Then you have to close and re-open the preferences window.

Now you can check "Show Banshee in Sound Menu" under the general tab.

After that it should work!